# Masonry with facebook embed posts

Tags: facebook, wordpress, dynamic, jquery-masonry

I am creating a wordpress theme with masonry. I am having a problem with facebook embed posts as masonry items. the height is unknown when masonry hits, so the columns overlap.

Is there a way to wait until the facebook posts are loaded for masonry to start arranging them ?

Answer (score 0):

You can start addding them once the event xfbml.render is fired

```
FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', function(){
 itemToAdd = facebookElementsMansory.shift();
 msnry.prepended(document.getElementById(itemToAdd), document.getElementById('facebook'));
});
```

where items can be stored in itemToAdd list